# text-overflow: ellipsis not working in a nested flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a component which consists of text next to a button. The text must shrink and get cut off if not enough space is available. Like this:

```css
.container .box {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.container .text {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">This is a text that is supposed to get truncated properly when needed.</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**Important:** To see it working, maximize the snippet and shrink the browser window in order to see the text truncate.

And it works fine as you can see.

#### Inside another flex container

The problem comes when I try to put this component inside another flex container.

My page consists of a side area, fixed, and the remaining part on the right which adjust to the space remaining. My component must fit into this second part, so I put it there:

```css
.container .box {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.container .text {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main .side {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.main .content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">This is a text that is supposed to get truncated properly when needed.</div>
      <div class="box">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the second case, the text does not shrink. I am using Chrome but it looks like a problem also in other browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Solution

Add `min-width: 0` to the outer flex item (`.content` / [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8w4vnwb2/))

or

Add `overflow: hidden` to the outer flex item (`.content` / [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8w4vnwb2/1/))

---

### Explanation

An initial setting of a flex container is `min-width: auto` on flex items.

This means that **a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content**.

In your original code, the text box (a flex item) gets smaller due to `overflow: hidden`.

Without that rule, you'll have the same behavior as the second example.

[Demo: When `overflow: hidden` is removed, first example behaves like second example](https://jsfiddle.net/gu01p9k1/).

In the second version of your code, the primary flex items are `.side` and `.content`.

By default, `.content` cannot be shorter than its content (regardless of `flex-shrink`)... until you override `min-width: auto` with `min-width: 0` or, like the first example, apply `overflow: hidden`.

*From the spec:*

> [**4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1... [read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

For another example see: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

Comment: Great explanation @Michael_B, i agree this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: I now get it! This is the clarification I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Setting `min-width:0` works in chrome but not in IE... `overflow:hidden` works on both

Answer (score 5):

Use `width` property to work with `overflow`

**Note:** Width should be in **px**

```css
.container .box {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.container .text {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.main .side {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.main .content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">This is a text that is supposed to get truncated properly when ndgsdgeeded.</div>
      <div class="box">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Its because of `flex: 1 1 auto;`  the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` only works when you have width property with static value.

Comment: Man, very cool! How did you get it? Sometimes I think that CSS needs some values in order to have all the model work, in this case with overflow I can consider it a general rule as a dimensions is needed to know where to start truncating right?