# Can't get the dots to show in a nested flex control

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, ellipsis

As shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/9gxjd651/8/), the first cell has no room and gets cut off. However, I lack the ellipsis there.

When I googled the issue, I've got [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660810/1525840) that I might want to add *overflow:hidden* to the parent component. So I did. To every component. To to use whatsoever.

```
div.data-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.data-row-cell {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.data-row-caption {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: please pay attention to the use of tags .. *flex* isn't *flexbox*

Comment: as a side note, the issue is not related to nested flexbox, your issue is related to the last flexbox container whataver the number of nesting we have.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I meant that the nesting isn't causing the issue, you will still have the issue even with a single flex container (like in the duplicate question)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I always thought that *flex* was just a shorthand for *flexbox*. Isn't it?

Comment: no, StackOverflow is not only about HTML/CSS, it's about programming in all the languages, so *flex* refer to something else .. simply hover in the tag when you add it to read the description of it.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. Thank you for educating me. At work, we're doing mostly MS/Win stuff so I believe that we developed a sub-lingo where flex refers to CSS. Nevertheless, your remark is generally correct and I do appreciate being set straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the ellipsis working by adding an additional element inside the `flex` child and setting the ellipsis styles on *that* element.

```css
div.data-row-caption {
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.data-row-caption>span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-row-cell data-row-caption">
  <span>{{caption that is really long}}</span>
</div>
<div class="data-row-cell data-row-value">{{data}}</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I took the liberty to short down your example to point out the most relevant part of the change. It's going (hopefully) to be easier for the next reader to see the actual golden spot. +1 too!